# Can antimatter exists in the form of compound?

Tags: particle-physics, antimatter

I just found an article describing the cooling of the antimatter, ["Laser cooling of antihydrogen atoms"](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-021-03289-6). Naturally, if there's something, one turned to be like to hold it.

Once the antihydrogen had formed with $e^+ e^-$ pair, the $\bar p$ became the "nucleus" of a charged particle, like an ion with a negative charge. Then, since electromagnetic force acted in a much longer distance than the strong force, is it possible to make a $\bar H^-$ to form a compound with, say $Ni^+$ and form $\bar HN_i$ by annihilating or getting rid of a pair of $e^+e^-$?

Naively thinking, once that's done, they were essentially trapped in the electron cloud, and, then, can they be picked up just like any other materials?

Comment: What does "one turned to be like to hold it" mean?

Comment: There are no $e^+ e^-$ pairs in antihydrogen. It consists of positrons and antiprotons.

Comment: @PM2Ring Yes, but they used $e^+e^-$ shower to create it in the firs place.

Comment: I think what you're asking is whether, in theory, antihydrogen and antioxygen could both exist, and react to form antiwater. CPT invariance makes me think yes.

Comment: @J.G. Maybe, although the question asks about a compound of antimatter with regular matter. That's also possible, but it doesn't last very long.

Comment: @PM2Ring Well spotted. However, I don't think stability is the issue in that example. Nickel's electrons will repel an antiproton, shielding it from the nickel nucleus, so the formation of the species hinges on energy scale.

Comment: @J.G. True. In fact, CERN are currently doing experiments with a hybrid formed by replacing an electron in helium with an antiproton. See https://home.cern/science/experiments/asacusa

Comment: FWIW, to make antihydrogen, the antiprotons are produced by smashing a proton beam into an iridium target. The positrons come from the decay of a positron emitter, sodium-22 (which has a half-life of 2.6 years). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiproton#Production & https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATRAP_experiment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your proposal of binding antihydrogen with an atom  made of particles ignores quantum mechanics.

Here is a discussion of  the [atomic orbitals,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbital) the probable locations of the electrons about the nucleus. In the molecule you envisage, the orbital of the antihydrogen positron has a high probability to  overlap with an electron orbital , and annihilating into two photons. The antiproton, because of its large mass will have an orbital within  the nucleus, with high probability of annihilating with a proton or neutron.

[Muonic atoms)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exotic_atom#Muonic_atoms) give an experimental confirmation of what happens when heavier particles take over the(n,l,m) of an electron orbital.

[image: exotic helium]

> Since the orbital of the muon is very near the atomic nucleus, that muon can be considered as a part of the nucleus.

....

> Since there is only one electron outside the nucleus, the hydrogen-4.1 atom can react with other atoms. Its chemical behavior is that of a hydrogen atom and not a noble helium atom.

So the nuclear structure changes , when a muon occupies one of the two  electrons location, ( n, l,m) quantum numbers.

The antiproton in your proposal  will have an even tighter orbital and will be within the positive nucleus,  an orbital with a good probability of overlap and annihilation with another nucleon .

So the answer is, antimatter cannot exist in a compound with matter in stable form.

Comment: It's supposed to let the electrons to annihilate and so that the $\bar H^-$ were to bind with the nuclei. It wouldn't be enough to be penetrate to the nuclei because of the electron cloud would it? The nuclei were both too heavy and thus shared different wavelength to interact.

Comment: @ShoutOutAndCalculate  If you read the muonic atom link, you will see that because of the higher mass of the muon the orbital of the muon is practivally touching the nucleus, and is counted within the nucleus for its chemical properties. The antiproton is ten times heavier and its orbital will not be within the electron cloud but within the nucleus. That is what difference the quantum mechanical behavior to the classical example of electron clouds.

Comment: But will it? The solution to electron obits was in hydrogen atom alone of a single electron. It didn't account for more electrons, and certainly not for the ones with a $\bar p^-$. The particle with the same electric charge repeal each other, and by forming a compound the $\bar p^-$ saw the outer "shell" first(though it's not electron). Proton mass was 2000 times larger than electron and the $e^{-2000}$ was quite some small probability if start the interaction from outside.

Comment: The difference in logic might be, atomic orbits was more in line of thinking $\bar p^-$ as some "intrinsic" object. but in molecular bound, the heavy particles were somewhat localized and "independent" while being "mediated" by the electrons. They were two solutions. The probability amplitude of the wave function of a heavy $\bar p$ to through the electron barrier and overlap with the other one might be low.

Comment: read the example of the muonic atoms.  The hydrogen has nice wuantum mechanical solutions, but there are solutions for hydrogen type atoms too and approximations for molecules. The probability amplitude of the antiproton is within the nucleus, it is not within the electron orbitals(not orbits). again, read the example of the muonic  atoms

Comment: Yes, at "lowest energy states" it doesn't work. I was too simplified to think it as a static situation. Rather, by constructing the Lagrangian and use Gauss law, it seemed that there might be a dynamics repulsion going on with the electron system and $\bar p^-$ trying to decay to the lower orbit. The reduced mass for $\mu_e\approx \mu_{p}$, and to reduce the radial energy in $\bar \mu^-$ it affected the entire Lagrangian of $27$ $e^-$ not only because of the $n$ but also $Z$. So the question settled into a lagrangian constrain and a transition probability. Thank you for the help. It made sense

Comment: Let $a+1$ be the number of proton in the other atom, it's a game between A change of energy of $\frac{2a^2+a}{(a^2+2a+1)}$ and $\frac{1}{n^2}$, so the transition probability might be relative low for it to be observed. For helium, it's around $1.1$ of the original energy so it's expected that it to happen easily with relative low thermal background, consistent with muonic atom you mentioned, as it's just the lowest ground states energy. (A "warm bath" might help to sustain the system.)

Comment: You are mixing quantum and classical. Gauss'es law is already withing the wavefunction solutions for the particular problem. It is not a matter of change in energy, the energy levels are determined by the numbers entered , which includes the masses of the electron and antiproton. The antiproton orbital is within the nucleus, not among the electrons.

Comment: But to get the antiproton into the nucleus rang orbit $n=1,2,...$ doesn't just happen, and to consider the instance of when it "does" before got annihilated, the effective potential seen by the electron could had already been drastically changed. It's easier to put it analog with gauss, but essential the potential term in the schrodinger equation was effectively modified. It's easier to think it as a transition probability. It won't be exact but might be close. The only thing one worried about was the $\bar p^-$ wave funciton fuse in "between" electron cloud which could accelerate the process.

Comment: (In terms of the evolution of the wave functions.)

Comment: (Might collect the discussion in another answer, but here's the key observation.) It's exactly because when at $n=1$ the $\bar p^{-}$ was close to nuclei range and that its wavelength was small compare to electron. Labeling $n_{\bar p^{-}}$ and $n_{e}$, when $n_{\bar p^{-}}$  started at a larger number in the outer orbit. Normally one would expect particles such electron in hydrogen just decay to lowest energy states. However, in this case, $\bar p^-$ eventually would reach a point where it needed to absorb energy in order for further decay from the interaction terms. Thus stability.

Comment: The antiproton because of its large mass will have a tight radius within the nucleus, no matter the n,lm that the electron would have had . You are completely off. Lets stop it here

Comment: You were correct in the case of atomic number $Z$ to be small in QM. I summarized the discussion in a post. If no one's going to make any further comment I'm going to accept your answer, but the decay to the "lowest energy states" doesn't just happen for the case where the atomic number $Z$ was large.

Answer (score 0):

Topics involved:

Notice that the process meant for $e^-e$ pair to annihilate each other in the very beginning to create ion like structure.

1. Pauli's exclusion principle: while Pauli's exclusion principle worked for fermions, the electron and anti proton were two types of particles for the interests of the situation. Thus it's rather most useful to think $\bar p^-$ and $e^-$ to be two independent systems from the beginning, labeled by two quantum number $n_{\bar p^-}$ and $n_{e}$.
2. Though the usual question was to ask what's the wave function of the [Exotic atom or Muonic atoms or "Hydrogen 4.1"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exotic_atom), the configuration of those were known and it didn't work because $\bar p^-$ when treated like hydrogen atom's electron had 2000 times mass than electron, and it's interaction were around the nuclei nuclei range.(see anna v's answer. ) At $n_{\bar p^-}=1,2,...$ , the overlap between the wave function of the $\bar p^-$ and nuclei was significant, thus the annihilation process was expected to happen with a high probability. ([a solution to the hydrogen atom could be of useful](https://users.aber.ac.uk/ruw/teach/327/hatom.php), see anna v's answer.)

However, question regarded was to send  $\bar H^-$ to ions such as $Ni^+$ from the outside. It's a dynamic process rather than a static one. The question of interest here was for $n_{\bar p^-}$ to be a larger number, i.e. 2000000, and then transit to the state of $n_{\bar p^-}=1,2,...$.

3. For the interest of the situation, during the scale of nuclei one could assume that the probability distribution of the electron mass coincide with the probability distribution of the electron charge. In face, that's how Lagrangian was written.

*Change in electron cloud lagrangian*

Once that's done, take for one instance to think the condition of when $\bar p^-$ was inside the nuclei with $n_{\bar p^-}=1,2,...$, the effective Lagrangian for electrons were no longer $\frac{Ze^2}{2\pi\epsilon_0 r}$ but rather $\frac{(Z-1)e^2}{2\pi\epsilon_0 r}$. The energy of the electron cloud had already been drastically changed.

Let $a+1=Z$ be the number of the original nuclei, this lead to a percentage change of $\frac{2a+1}{(a+1)^2}$ per electron's original energy, or a percentage change of $\frac{2a^2 -a-1}{(a+1)^2}$ of the combined energy of the electron could. Notice that in the Muonic helium this never mattered, because for $a=1$, $\frac{2a^2 -a-1}{(a+1)^2}=0$(corrected) consistent with the fact anna v had mentioned, that in Muonic helium the other conditions simply didn't matter, where $n_{\bar p^-}$ were free to decay and annihilate in the overlap of the wave functions.

However, that's not the same case for Nikel, for Nikel, $a=27$, and $\frac{2a^2 -a-1}{(a+1)^2}=1.8239$. This drastic change had to be considered, other wise the charge conservation and on shell condition wouldn't hold. This created a sort of "repulsion" of electron cloud with high atomic number unseen from that of the Muonic helium, or the "shelding" of the nuclei from the electron cloud.

*Transition probability*(incomplete)

Thus, the more relevant value was to calculate **A.** the transition probability of the process $$|n_{\bar p^-}(high)\rangle \otimes|a+1,n_e\rangle\Rightarrow |n_{\bar p^-}(low)\rangle \otimes|a,n_e\rangle$$. However, one had to consider **B.** what if $\bar p^-$ started to push the atom one states by another and thus "fuse" through one layer of the electron cloud to another. This would increase the probability and had to be discussed. Further, though the fact that $m_{\bar p^-}$ was much larger to be comparable, it also lead to $\mu_{\bar p^-}=2000 \mu_e$, and this increased the probability of the transition to happen by composite the energy of the $\bar \mu^-$.

*Change in $\bar p^-$ energy*

The above discussion only talked about the electron system, notice that the sheilding also meant a change in the $\bar p^-$ energy as well, i.e.
$$E_{\bar p^-}\propto -\frac{2000 \mu_e 1^2}{(n_{\bar p^-}large)^2}\Rightarrow  -\frac{2000\mu_e Z^2}{(1,2...)^2}$$ of $\Delta E_{\bar p^-}\approx -\frac{2000\mu_e Z^2}{(1,2...)^2}$. But $\Delta E_{total_e}<\frac{(2Z^2-Z)\mu_e}{1^2}$. That had already brought suspension.
Calculating
$$\Delta E_{p,\alpha,a}= \frac{2000\mu_e (a+1)^2}{(n_p+\alpha)^2}- \frac{2000\mu_e (a)^2}{(n_p)^2}  \approx \frac{2000\mu_e}{n_p+\alpha} (\frac{\alpha(a+1)+2a n_p  }{n_p^2}) \approx \frac{2000\mu_e}{n_p+\alpha} (\frac{c*a}{n_p})$$ where $n_p\sim \alpha>>c,a$, while
$$\Delta E_{e,a}= -\frac{\mu_e (a+1)^2}{n_e^2}+ \frac{\mu_e (a)^2}{n_e^2}= -\frac{\mu_e (2a+1)}{n_e^2}$$.
Notice that in the above notation, the $a$ for $e$ and $a$ for $p$ was different and with a sum of the atomic number $Z$.

For [$Ni$ (atomic number $28$)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nickel), $a=27$, and if filled to the out shell of $n_e=3$.

***Hypothesis*** (**B.**)
Thus, though the "lowest" energy states was for $n_p$ reduce to $1,2,...$, the effect of the electron cloud provided some sort of repulsion, where at $n_p$  large, the reduction of $n_p$ would eventually reach to a point where it required the absorption of the energy to enable the further quantized orbital decay to the nearby lower energy states $n_p-\alpha$.
(**A**.)For at least three energetic photon to mediate the process and taking into the consideration of spin, it took some probability to happen. But it doesn't just happen.

When the atomic number $Z$ was small, anna v's answer pretty much summarized it in QM.